# How to select all cells between two cells, where more may be inserted later?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to count all the cells that have information between two cells that are in the same column.

This is easy enough to do using `=countif(cell1:cell2, "<>")` the problem is that I may need to update the cells at some point and *insert* new cells between cell1 and cell2, in which case this new cell will not be counted.

Is there anything I can do other than manually updating the formula every time?

Comment: Do you know what is a `cell range`? Do you know what happens to a `cell range reference` when the related `cell range` is moved?

Answer (score 2):

As  Rubén hinted in a comment, the cell range reference cell1:cell2 will be automatically updated if you insert or delete cells within the range. For example: if you have a formula

```
=countif(A2:A10, "<>")
```

and insert a row between 2nd and 10th, the command will automatically change to

```
=countif(A2:A11, "<>")
```

Comment: I was wondering if could be necessary to refer the OP to something like http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/8 :)